# how to make a local domain available on all computers on lan

Tags: dns, localhost, server, lamp, lan

I have 10 computers and i want to fetch my local host on all the systems . I am using ubuntu 12.04 . I changed my hosts file like this

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ri8-MS-7788
192.168.1.22    manojdhiman.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

my projects are available on other computers with ip address if i hit url like **http://192.168.1.22/** but not available if i use **http://manojdhiman.com/**

Answer (score 8):

There are two basic ways to achieve what you want:

- populate and maintain (synchronize) /etc/hosts (or Windows equivalent) files on all your computers,
- maintain a local DNS server, and configure all your computers (either directly or via DHCP) to use that DNS server.

Depending on the rate of changes (once per year or several times per day), it may or may not be sensible to automate the synchronization of the hosts files. The DNS server automatically solves the synchronization issue.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work, you would need to add line 3 to the host file on ALL systems on your network.

Comment: its working if i do like this , but is there any other way without change the other computers configuration ??

Answer (score 0):

> my projects are available on other computers with ip address if i hit
>   url like http://192.168.1.22/ but not available if i use
>   http://manojdhiman.com/

If you just want to like that, you can change the DNS of your client. If your client is Windows OS, you can change the `Alternate DNS Server` to `192.168.1.22`, please read [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings#1TC=windows-7) for more detail and if your client is Linux OS you can add/change `/etc/resolv.conf` to :

```
nameserver 192.168.1.22
```

Please read [this](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/changing-dns-settings-on-linux) how to change DNS in Linux.

If you want to more flexible to change that `DNS`, you can change your `DHCP Configurations` to add your `IP Address` to the `DNS`, so the computer can get it via `DHCP` instead you change it manually at one by one client computers.

Hope this will help you out. :)